/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found VSCode SSH remote after clearing remote server home directory
I accidentally clear everything in the home directory on the remote server. If I connect to the remote VM (server) with SSH VSCode, I will get this kind of error
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found

I'm currently using Remote - SSH 0.108.0.
The OS is ubuntu 16.04
I don't have suoder permission on the remote server. Normal SSH is still working well.
I'm not sure about the part cleaning the remote server home directory
I accidentally init the git repo at the home directory, it marks everything as newly added files with a green color, I type in git clean -fdx without notice and boom. Things are all gone except the .ssh folder. It still lemme work on it till I close the connection.
